# If $A \cup B$ = $A$ or $A \cap B = A$, what can we conclude about the sets $A$ and $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1) If $A \cup B$ = $A$, what can we conclude about the sets $A$ and $B$?

2) If $A \cap B = A$, what can we conclude about the sets $A$ and $B$?

So, for $(1)$ we can say $A = B$ or $B = \emptyset$

and for $(2)$ we can say $A = B$ only

right?

Comment: Nope. Think about a circle sitting inside a circle.

Comment: Not quite. Write out the definitions of $A \cap B$ and $A \cup B$, and see if that helps...

Comment: for $A\U B=A$ surely this means that B is an empty set?

Comment: @HenryLee: no. Read my comment.

Comment: @symplectomorphic as yes that is a good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ If $A\cup B=A$, then we can say that $B$ is a subset $($fully lies within $)$ of $A$.

Hence, $B\subset A$

$2)$ If $A\cap B=A$, then we can that $A$ is a subset $($fully lies within $)$ of $B$.

Hense, $A\subset B$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$. Also $A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $B \subseteq A \cup B$.